# How to wait Arduino ready with ANY method?

Tags: usb, linux

Recently I knew, that Arduino restarts any time somebody accesses it's serial port. I was trying to use this feature so that for each request Arduino restarts and give answer on request. Unfortunately, I found this is impossible with shell script, because shell script can't keep port open all time I send requests and wait responses: Arduino restarts on each port touch.

So, I wrote simple C++ program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void help() {
    cout << "bmp180dims usage:" << endl <<
            "bmp180dims port command" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if( argc != 3 ) {
        help();
        return 0;
    }

    fstream port;
    string answer;

    port.open(argv[1], std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);

    port << argv[2] << endl;

    port >> answer;

    cout << answer << endl;

    port.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Since this program has explicit `open` and `close` statements, I was thinking, this program will wait for Arduino answer, because of stream reading functions. But I failed again: this program returns nothing as if it is not waiting.

Why?

Apparently, the only way to communicate with Arduino, is to have daemon program, which always listen it's port. Is this really so?

Arduino-side code is here: [How can program/arduino restarted by IDE?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16769/how-can-program-arduino-restarted-by-ide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, you're *not waiting for the bootloader to complete* before sending your text:

```
port.open(argv[1], std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
// Board resets and enters bootloader

port << argv[2] << endl;
// You send argv[2] to the bootloader

port >> answer;
// The bootloader doesn't understand what you sent so doesn't reply with anything
```

You *must* wait for the bootloader to complete *before* sending ANYTHING to the Arduino.

The two ways you can do that are:

1. Insert a `sleep(3);` immediately after opening the port to give the bootloader a chance to time out and start running your sketch, or
2. Provide an initial "I Am Ready" message from your sketch that your C++ program waits for *before* sending the text you want to send to elicit an answer.

Comment: I understand that I am not waiting for send, but I am waiting for receive. Why `port >> answer` not waiting if bootloader sends nothing? Shouldn't `port >> answer` wait for space or newline?

Comment: It can only wait for something if you are sending something. You aren't sending anything because you aren't receiving anything, because what you send isn't getting through to your sketch.

Comment: How this is implemented? How `>>` can know that I didn't send anything? How it can distinguish silence from delay between request and response and initial silence? Suppose I implement your suggestion on "I Am Ready" how can I wait for "I Am Ready" if `>>` will just drop waiting when it wants?

Comment: P.S. Note that my questions are for understand what is happening

Comment: If the port is opened in non-blocking mode then it will never wait for anything, ever.  I don't use fstream so don't know how it opens the port - if it's non blocking then you cannot use >> to read from it.  You should be using low level IO for talking to a serial port, not file IO.  Use open(), read() and write(), with a good smattering of select() to see if there is actually anything to read from the port.